# JavaScript scope: preserve object in array in function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, scope

I am using `.map()` on an array inside a function. I am not modifying the array itself (`arr = arr.map(...)`), but rather creating a new array (`var arr2 = arr.map(...)`).

Yet, this still modifies the original `arr` outside my function (which I don't want). How can I preserve?

```
var arr = [{prop: 1}];
myFunction(arr);
console.log(arr[0].prop); // returns 2, I want it to return 1

function myFunction(arr) {
  var arr2 = arr.map(obj => {
    obj.prop = 2;
    return obj;
  }); 
  console.log(arr[0].prop); // returns 2
}
```

Comment: `obj.prop = 2` modifies the object in the array, since `obj` is a reference to the same object, not a clone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It modifies based on its reference. If you want to create a new object and modify its properties then you need to use [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Read the documentation:

> Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression or string
>   to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function
>   calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object
>   expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs
>   (for object literals) are expected.

You can try the following:

```js
var arr = [{prop: 1}];
myFunction(arr);

function myFunction(arr) {
  var arr2 = arr.map(obj => {
    let copyObj = {...obj};
    
    copyObj.prop = 2;
    return copyObj;
  }); 
  
  console.log(arr[0].prop); 
  console.log(arr2[0].prop); 
}
```

Comment: Or just `.map((obj) => ({ ...obj, prop: 2 }))`, but it's worth noting this is a *shallow* copy.

Comment: Ah that's a great use of the spread operator. Thanks!